# cmtt as font in texttt

Tags: fonts, typewriter

I am using libertine fonts and I would like to change the `texttt` command to use the `cmtt` font.
I tried :

```
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont{#1}}
```

but it seems to switch the font for all the text coming after the `texttt` command. If I type `before \texttt{center} after`, I want only `center` to be in `cmtt`. How to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you load the `libertine` package, do

```
\usepackage[tt=false]{libertine}
```

With other font packages, if they don't provide a suitable option, just do

```
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}
```

after having loaded the font package.

Redefining `\texttt` in the way you tried is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Another good looking monospace font is Beramono:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=0.88]{beramono}
...
```